# how to only change display when submit button is pressed and not when search is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

currently the user doesn't see anything below the search bar until they submit a search pressing the submit button because it changed the userState for displaying the data to true. after they press the button once the display changes as the user is typing and they no longer need to press the submit button to see a change in the display. i dont want it to do that

i want the display to only change when they press the submit button but im not sure how to do that

```
 function Schedule(props){
    //array hook for calendar data
    const [calendars,setCalendars] = useState([])
    //string hook for what the user searches
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    //used to inform user of when data is loading
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
   //array hook for filtering out calendars as user is typing
   const [filteredCalendars, setFilteredCalendars] = useState([]);

// get schedules for playlists from API (in this case, JSON files)
useEffect(()=>{
    setLoading(true);
    fetch('data/scheduled_playlist.json',{
       headers:{
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
   }).then(function(response){
       console.log("hello")
       console.log(response)
       return response.json()
   }).then(function(jsonCalendars){
       console.log(jsonCalendars)
       setCalendars(jsonCalendars)
       setLoading(false);
   })
},  [])

useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredCalendars(
        calendars.filter( calendar =>
            calendar.storeID.toString().startsWith(search)
        )
    );
  }, [search, calendars]);

if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading calendars...</p>;
}



function showDisplay() {
    setDisplay(true);
}

var result = "";
if (display) {
    result = <div>
            {filteredCalendars.map((calendar) => ( 
            <Calendar calendar={calendar}/>))}
        </div>
    // setSearch(" ");
}

return(
    <div>
        <div className="text-center">
            <h1>Schedule Playlists</h1>
        </div>                        

        <Form onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault(); showDisplay()}}>
            <div className="search-box">
                <BsSearch/> <input type="text"  placeholder="Search calendar by store ID..." onSubmit = {e => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
                <Button type="submit">Submit form</Button>
            </div>
            
        </Form>

        <div>
            {result}
        </div>



    </div>
    
)
}

   export default Schedule
```

Comment: Can you please clean up the question a bit? State the current behavior and desired behavior as clearly and simply as possible. Thanks!

Comment: i changed it @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second useEffect, you are updating `filteredCalenders` every time `search` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredCalendars(
        calendars.filter( calendar =>
            calendar.storeID.toString().startsWith(search)
        )
    );
  }, [calendars]);
```

Removing `search` from the dependency array will make it so that `setFilteredCalendars` only gets called when `calendars` changes.

Here's a link to the React docs on the useEffect array if you would like more info:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: I did this and now when I search something it just displays the whole list from my data and doesnt let me search again